# Concatenation code not working as intended

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a code in Excel VBA for concatenating values upto 7 columns in a row with ^ between them. I noticed that if I enter the same value in the first six columns, I get the output without the ^.  This doesn't happen if i fill upto column 7 or 5. The code is as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click() 
    Cells(2, 1).Select  
    Dim stri As String, eaid_1 As String, eaid_2 As String, eaid_3 As String, _
        eaid_4 As String, eaid_5 As String, eaid_6 As String, eaid_7 As String
    Do Until Selection.Value = ""     
        eaid_1 = Selection.Value     
        eaid_2 = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value     
        eaid_3 = Selection.Offset(0, 2).Value     
        eaid_4 = Selection.Offset(0, 3).Value     
        eaid_5 = Selection.Offset(0, 4).Value     
        eaid_6 = Selection.Offset(0, 5).Value     
        eaid_7 = Selection.Offset(0, 6).Value          
        stri = eaid_1 & "^" & eaid_2 & "^" & eaid_3 & "^" & eaid_4 & "^" & eaid_5 _
                      & "^" & eaid_6 & "^" & eaid_7          
        Selection.Offset(0, 8).Value = stri     
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select  
    Loop  

    Cells(2, 9).Select  
    Dim x As String, y As String, z As String  
    Do Until Selection.Value = ""  
        x = Selection.Value 
        y = Right(x, 6) 
        z = Replace(y, "^", "")  
        x = Replace(x, y, z)          
        Selection.Offset(0, 0).Value = x 
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select  
    Loop  
End Sub
```

Comment: That is the effect you get with the code in he second loop. If you remove that loop, this will not happen. So the question becomes: what was your intention with that second loop. FYI: it removes the `^` from the last 6 characters. That can give quite unexpected results, since the values between two `^` may have differing lengths. So sometimes one `^` will be removed, sometimes 2, ... etc.

Comment: also, try to avoid using `Cells(2, 1).Select` and later on use `eaid_2  = Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value` , instead use `eaid_2 = Cells(2, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value` . or to be more dynamic. `Dim Rng as Range` , `Set Rng = Range("B1")` , and then `eaid_2 = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value` , this will let you later to update your selected range much faster and easier

Comment: you could as well. just put the entire code into Array, `Dim eaid() as Variant`, and your code code look much neater and easier to debug

Comment: The second loop is to remove ^ from end suppose I don't fill the entire 7 columns and that is necessary for my work. All my entries will be greater than 6 characters in length, so unwanted removal is not an issue, based on character length at least. I had set it as a separate loop, but jined with the main part to make my work easier. But i don't see the how the issue comes only when upto row 5 is filled with the same value. FYI, the issue occurs when I test with a scenario that i won't be using, but I'd like to debug it.

Comment: @Shai_Rado: Can you please explain the Array part? I'm new to coding. I knew my code was functional but ugly. I'd welcome suggestions to make it less clumsy.

Comment: @VishnuNath see my post below, not sure it's answer all of your post, but it's a way to dynamically read values per rows into array and then into combined string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 7
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range

    Set c = Cells(2, 1)
    Do While c.Value <> ""
        Set rng = c.Resize(1, Application.CountA(c.Resize(1, NUM_COLS)))
        c.Offset(0, NUM_COLS).Value = _
               Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Value)), "^")
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Some explanation:

- You should avoid using `Select`/`Activate` to work with ranges, and instead use a Range variable (such as `c` above)
- The `DoWhile...Loop` starts at A2 and continues until `c` is blank
- The `rng` variable represents a Range object beginning at `c` and extending to the right for as many cells as there are values (to a maximum of 7 cells). The `CountA` worksheet function is used to count the number of values, and `Resize` creates a range of the required size.
- The repeated `Application.Transpose` creates a single-dimension array out of the 2-D array resulting for `rng.Value`.  Don't ask me to explain exactly why that works ;-)
- Finally, `Join` takes the 1-D array and returns a single string with each element of the input array concatenated to the next and separated by the second argument ("^")

Comment: You beat me to it! `Join()` has to be the way to go. If you changed the resized range to `c.Resize(1, NUMCOLS).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` then he'd also get round the problem of jagged rows (ie empty cells at the end of each row).

Comment: @Ambie I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for the code. Can you please explain what happens in the loop? I'm new to coding, so if you can help me here, it'll be great! Thank you :)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks a lot for the help Tim!

Answer (score 1):

The code below will "**CONCATENATE**" each row (where Column A has data) and checks each row where the last Column has data, then it combines them together (adding "**^**" between each array elements). Currently it puts the result string in **Column I**, like in your post).

What is the purpose your second loop ? what your final result should look like ?

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim Rng             As Range
Dim stri            As String
Dim eaid()          As Variant
Dim lRow            As Long
Dim i               As Long
Dim LastColumn      As Long

' start from Cell A2
lRow = 2
Do Until Range("A" & lRow).Value = ""
    ' get the last column with data in current row
    LastColumn = Cells(lRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ReDim eaid(1 To LastColumn)

    Set Rng = Range("A" & lRow)

    ' read all Range values to one-dimension array using Transpose
    eaid = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Rng.Resize(1, LastColumn).Value))

    ' read all array elements to String
    For i = LBound(eaid) To UBound(eaid)
        If i = LBound(eaid) Then
            stri = stri & eaid(i)
        Else
            stri = stri & "^" & eaid(i)
        End If
    Next i

    Rng.Offset(0, 8).Value = stri
    stri = ""
    lRow = lRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```